# Passing control from one class to an event handler from another class

Tags: vb.net, class, parameter-passing

I have a TextBox1 in Form1. I need to pass it to another class (in class libraries/another project). So, that instance of class can modify what inside TextBox1 within the entire class (not just a scope). For my problem i need to pass it to an event handler.

```
Public Class TheClass

    WithEvents Timer1 As New Timer

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Timer1.Tick

    End Sub

End Class
```

I can think of passing by reference. But, I can't find a way to pass TextBox1 to that event handler.

What should I do to make the Timer1 have access to modify TextBox1 in Form1?

Comment: If the tick event will reference some control, it should be available to `TheClass` as a member variable.  You dont pass anything to event handlers

Answer (score 0):

If `TheClass` is created after `Form1`, you can use constructor injection in order to pass a reference of `Form1` to `TheClass`.

```
Public Class TheClass

    Private WithEvents Timer1 As New Timer
    Private m_form1 As Form1

    Public Sub New (ByVal form1 as Form1)
        m_form1 = form1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Timer1.Tick

        m_form1.TextBox1.Text = "tick"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that `TextBox1` must be Public or Friend.

---

Another way is to add a public event to `TheClass`.

```
Public Class TheClass

    Public Event Tick()

    Private WithEvents Timer1 As New Timer

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Timer1.Tick

        RaiseEvent Tick()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now the form can handle this event.

```
' In Form1
Private WithEvents theObj As New TheClass

Private Sub theObj_Tick() _
    Handles theObj.Tick

    Me.Textbox1.Text = "tick"
End Sub
```

Now you can keep `Textbox1` private and `TheClass` does not need to know anything about a textbox.

The event handler can also have parameters

```
' In TheClass
Public Event Tick(ByVal counter As Integer)

...

Counter += 1
RaiseEvent Tick(Counter)
```

and

```
' In Form1
Private Sub theObj_Tick(ByVal counter As Integer) _
    Handles theObj.Tick

    Me.Textbox1.Text = "counter = " & counter
End Sub
```